# anonymous method alternative for Vb.net is there any Design pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sharepoint, design-patterns

With C# anonymous delegates, we can avoid declaration of extra method, I know in VB.NET they're not available, but is there a design pattern that I can use so that I can avoid writing an extra method each time? I need it for SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges which will be used a lot of times in our code.

for example

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
                    delegate()
                    {
                        //some code here. 
                    }
                );
```

I want in VB.NET to do something like:

```
using RunWithElevatedPrivil() 
'some code here. 
end using
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this link, it may help:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/4854962a-0d4e-40e4-909a-581bb7a5ab03

> In vb.net you can define a parameterless sub that does the code you
>   want executed with higher privileges and declare it as
>   CodeToRunElevated:
>
> You will have to define module level variables for it to use.
>
> Dim secureCode As New SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevated(AddressOf
>   Me.SPCode) SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(secureCode)

Comment: To make it an answer, quote a relevant part of that page here.

Comment: thanks its helps for my case :)  but is there a design pattern i can use for generally in vb.net ?